# Strange indexable styping

Tags: typescript

Typescript (2.0) doesn't give an error on this:

```
let x: { [index: string]: Object } = {1: 2}
```

I see there two potential errors:

1. Index field is number type but should be string
2. item type is number too but should be an Object type

Why does it passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the [Indexable Types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) it's noted that:

> There are two types of supported index signatures: string and number.
>   It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type
>   returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned
>   from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a number,
>   JavaScript will actually convert that to a string before indexing into
>   an object. That means that indexing with 100 (a number) is the same
>   thing as indexing with "100" (a string), so the two need to be
>   consistent.

Which is why it accepts it when you use a number as an index instead of a string.
Indexes are always strings.

2. In the part in the docs where [`Any` is explained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) it's noted that:

> ... variables of type Object only allow you to assign any value to
>   them ...

With the following example:

```
let prettySure: Object = 4;
```

Basically, `Object` can be anything.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.